# MongoDB equivalent for an SQL query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Any idea how to represent the following SQL condition for MongoDB

```
WHERE
     a = 1
AND  b = 2
AND  (c >= 3 OR c IS NULL)
AND  d = 4
```

Tried this, but seems not working:

```
{ a:1, b:2, c:{ $in:[ { $gte:3 }, { $exists: false } ] } , d:4 }
```

This doesn't work since the key 'c' gets overridden:

```
{ a:1, b:3, $or:[ { c:{ $gte:3 } }, { c:{ $exists:false } } ] , d:4 }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "$or": [
        {
            "c": {
                "$gte": 3
            }
        },
        {
            "c": {
                "$exists": false
            }
        }
    ],
    "d": 4
}